# Read from Access Database in python using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, ms-access

I am trying to read from an exported copy of an access database into python using SQL commands. I want to be able to write it locally while working from home then change the path later to read from the real database in the SQL server once back in the office.

I have a 64 bit machine with a 32 bit version of Python 2.7.16 and a 32 bit version of Microsoft Access

I am trying to use the following code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Python27\EKPC Scripts\FR Database Export 04302020.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * dbo_Branches')

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print (row)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Everything I have read is saying that the error is caused by either Python or Access being 64 bit instead of 32 but I have installed new copies to make sure that was not the case.

This is my first project using databases in a while so I'm not sure if I am just missing something small. Is there another issue I should be looking for?

Edit: The drivers listed after printing pyodbc.driver() are:

```
Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)
Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)
Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
SQL Server
```

Comment: Please print `pyodbc.drivers()` and see the available drivers on your machine.

Comment: `select * from dbo_branches` . Missing `from` ?

Comment: @Parfait The drivers are: 
Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)
Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)
Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)
Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )
Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)
Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)
Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)
Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)
Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)
Microsoft ODBC for Oracle
Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )
Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )
Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)
Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)
SQL Server

Comment: You need to install the 32-bit version of  `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` driver which you currently do not have. You can freely download via MS: [2010 download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255), [2016 download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). Do not select x64 version.